# configure express req.session with cookie disabled

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js webserver with express middleware. I am trying to eliminate the need to session stores for performance reasons. I dont track much as of now.

However, I do need to keep track of username and userid when a session is started after loggig in. I have implemented this using express res.cookie( ... ) which works if cookies are enabled. But it will not work if cookies are disabled.

so I was looking at req.session but that again uses cookieSession internally.

> Q1: How can I keep track of username (once user has loggedin )
>   across multiple requests with cookies disabled in browser and NO-SESSION-STORE
>   (REDIS/MONGO etc)
>
> Q2: In the solution for Q1 above, I want webserver to be stateless,
>   so it does not grow in memory at any point?

Is it possible? Does my question/requirement even make sense? I am new to this.

Essentially I am looking for an object other than cookie that can be part of request which will communicated every time request is sent/received

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple avenues you could potentially take, since it sounds like you control the requester as well as the backend service.

- HTTP Headers
- Query String
- Cookies

We know cookies are out.

With HTTP Headers, you can't always count on them unless you're making some kind of AJAX call.

Query strings require you to ALWAYS send back a user name or other identifier manually. However, it would solve Q1 and Q2.

Depending on what your app is, it might make sense to re-architect endpoints so that they are ReSTful and help define actions - that way it makes semantic sense to have a username as part of the request url.

For example:

```
GET http://example.com/:username => could display a profile
GET http://example.com/:username/friends => could display a list of friends.
```

Depending on how your app is designed, you might also be able to utilize websockets to handle user connections and auth.

Comment: thx for response...for now I am going the Google way  of letting users know cookies are disabled and ask them to enable if they want to access the site...I will out how that will work in prod....but I wll keep your suggestions in noitce...thx again

Comment: Np, good luck. Instead of taking the url scheme I mentioned above, you could also just append a ?uid=1u29nr39 to your urls and use that to identify a user. Just note that with the query string methodology you will also have to keep track of additional information to verify the authenticity of a user. Telling them to just enable cookies is a much easier method =)